# BaseGameUtils GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

After importing BaseGameUtils project as a library and fixing a couple of errors i came across these errors:

```
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mGamesApiOptions = null;
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mPlusApiOptions = null;
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mAppStateApiOptions = null;
```

the errors say GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions cannot be resolved to a type.
other errors i got:

```
public void setGamesApiOptions(GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions options) {
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mGamesApiOptions = options;
}
```

they say mGamesApiOptions cannot be resolved to a variable and the same as before for the GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions. i've already referenced the google_play_services_lib to the GameBaseUtils. ive looked on the internet for some explanation without succes, the only thing i found is this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup but didn't help much either because i didn't really understand what to do, can anyone help?
(btw i use eclipse)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

came across the same problem just now.. this solution worked

Use the code available here instead: https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

Just cut everything from the imports of GameHelper.java (BaseGameUtils) to the end of it and then paste the contents of that gist as a replacement.

Comment: I was getting Runtime exceptions until I changed (line 97) this `PlusOptions mPlusApiOptions = null;` for this `protected PlusOptions mPlusApiOptions = PlusOptions.builder().build();`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same problem with my app. I think they must have changed something in the most recent update to `GameHelper.java`. Here's something I tried, but just so you know, this only got rid of the errors so I could compile my code, it doesn't fix the source of the problem.

```
// Api options to use when adding each API, null for none
Games.GamesOptions mGamesApiOptions = null;
Plus.PlusOptions mPlusApiOptions = null;
Api.ApiOptions mAppStateApiOptions = null;
```

I also changed the methods further down so that the Classes matched...

```
/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the Games API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setGamesApiOptions(Games.GamesOptions options) {
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mGamesApiOptions = options;
}

/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the AppState API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setAppStateApiOptions(Api.ApiOptions options) {
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mAppStateApiOptions = options;
}

/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the Plus API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setPlusApiOptions(Plus.PlusOptions options) {
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mPlusApiOptions = options;
}
```

I was still getting errors so I finally just had to get rid of the second parameters of these `addApi()` method calls because they weren't accepting these Class types. Fortunately the `addApi()` method doesn't need the options parameter, but removing it pretty much defeats the entire purpose of having these variables in the first place.

```
if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_GAMES)) {
    builder.addApi(Games.API); //, mGamesApiOptions);
    builder.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES);
}

if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_PLUS)) {
    builder.addApi(Plus.API); //, mPlusApiOptions);
    builder.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);
}

if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_APPSTATE)) {
    builder.addApi(AppStateManager.API); //, mAppStateApiOptions);
    builder.addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE);
}
```

I really hope someone comes up with a real solution or they update the GameHelper file. This was a pretty annoying problem. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

EDIT: I found [when they changed this code in the GitHub project](https://github.com/gguuss/android-samples/commit/c2e6a2d66abaece3404f6a7b0e36e634470aca5d#diff-3a6d5d0891b00a30678ebc1c07821812). However these changes were committed over 3 months ago, so I'm very confused as to why no one else has had this problem. Here's what it looks like:

```
-    // Client objects we manage. If a given client is not enabled, it is null.
-    GamesClient mGamesClient = null;
-    PlusClient mPlusClient = null;
-    AppStateClient mAppStateClient = null;
+    // the Google API client builder we will use to create GoogleApiClient
+    GoogleApiClient.Builder mGoogleApiClientBuilder = null;

-    // What clients we manage (OR-able values, can be combined as flags)
+    // Api options to use when adding each API, null for none
+    GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mGamesApiOptions = null;
+    GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mPlusApiOptions = null;
+    GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mAppStateApiOptions = null;
+
+    // Google API client object we manage.
+    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
```

Comment: i did pretty much the same thing, deleted the errors, but i'm encountering other along the way of my project that include this nightmare of a BaseGameUtils library. i don't know why this is happening, i just hope that android studio will be 100% better than eclipse